# Visual Studio Database Project; SQLCMD reference all files in a folder

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sqlcmd, database-project

I have a database project with a pre-deployment script in which I reference several sql script and xml files. For example:

```
:r .\PostDeployment\StaticData.sql

DECLARE @xmlMyFile1 XML = 
$(APOS)
:r ..\..\ReferenceData\MyFile1.xml
$(APOS)
```

These work fine, however is there a way to reference each of the files in a folder programmatically so I don't have to specify each one individually?

I've tried searching online, but this topic is quite sparse and I have found no information directly relating to my question.

Comment: Your best bet would be to look up SQLCMD usage, but I don't know of a way to reference each file in a folder programmatically. I'd be wary of doing that anyway in case a rogue file got in that folder somehow. The SQLCMD reference is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx but I don't think all commands are supported so you'll probably have to manage each file separately. You could gen the file programmatically, though.